# No Such Module 'Alamofire'

Tags: json, xcode, swift2, alamofire

I manually installed alamofire using the tutorial on their GitHub. It was working great until I accidentally changed what used to be Alamofire.xcodeproj to ParkR.xcodeproj. Ever since then I have received the error.

```
No Such Module 'Alamofire'
```

I would be so grateful to anyone who can solve this as I have VERY limited time to finish my project and this error has stopped me in my tracks for 5+ hours now! THANKS!

Comment: I've rarely used xcode and nothing related to your project, but have you tried a full clean and build?

Comment: yes, I have created new project and re installed alamofire and the same issue persists!

Comment: hmm, have you checked other similar questions, i see several that might relate or help http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+such+Module+Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by another way by using cocoapod Depencency manager . It will take approx 10 minutes time to do . Create a new project and Just follow these steps :
1. Open the terminal and install cocoapod by just writing the command

```
 $ gem install cocoapods 
or $ sudo  gem install cocoapods
```

2. After  that  go to the path of your project on the terminal.

   $ cd "Write your path of the project or simply drag the project folder on the terminal"
3. Now crate the pod file by the command

   $ pod init

4 . open the pod file and write your dependency name like "pod 'Alamofire' " in your case . To open pod file

```
$ open -a xcode podfile
```

and just copy past the following in your pod file (not forget to change your

```
target name , if you are pasting this) 

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
    pod 'Alamofire',
end
```

5. Now , install your  dependencies  by

   $ pod install
6. Once the dependencies installation is successful . Close the project and open the newly crated .XCWORKSPACE file . And write import Alamofire on the top of your class . All the best and thanks